# Plots that varies over the time on Python Matplotlib with Jupyter

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder, jupyter

In the following lines I report a code that generates a plot changing over the time with Python on Anaconda Spyder

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.01)
N = 1
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
for N in range(8):
    y = np.sin(np.pi*x*N)
    line, = ax.plot(x, y)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.5)
    line.remove()
```

I would like to do the some with Jupyter, but it is not possible. Particularly it seems that the Matplotlib method .pause() does not exist on Jupyter.
Is there anyone who can explain me this difference and can help me building up a code for plots variating over the time with Python on Jupyter, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works for me if I select an `interactive backend` using the magic command `%matplotlib`; it is likely that your `Jupyter` notebook settings are set to display plots inline.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

%matplotlib

x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.01)
N = 1
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
for N in range(8):
    y = np.sin(np.pi*x*N)
    line, = ax.plot(x, y)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.5)
    line.remove()
```

To restore your setings, use the magic `%matplotlib inline`

Comment: This opens an external matplotlib window and works nicely. For animation inline I haven't see a solution yet. What does work inline however, is interactivity with 'interact', so one can show plots inline that change. Maybe there is a way to 'fake' a changing slider?

Comment: AFAIK, inline matplotlib plots can't, unfortunately, be interactive, unless you want to use an external JS library (interact widgets, or plotly, or maybe seaborn)

Comment: interactive works, do it all the time, just not animation. `%matplotlib inline
`import matplotlib.pyplot as p`
`from ipywidgets import *`
`import numpy as np`

`t = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.01)`

`def sine(a,f): 
   f=a*np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t)
   p.plot(t,f)
  p.ylim([-3,3])`
    
`interact( sine, a=[1,3,.01],f=[1,5,0.01])`